# Microsoft Edge/IE SVG transform scale animation doesnt work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

I have svg  scale animation on hover, it works in Chrome/Firefox/Opera,
but it does not work in Edge/IE

Example looks like: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/InteractiveSVG/
Circles are in g element, and g must scale from 0.5 to 1 on hover and back.
What is the best solution for this browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, svg transforms via css don't work in IE. there's a [comprehensive article](https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/) about it. Gsap js is to the rescue. I've sketched a fiddle to show how to transfer all css styles like transitions and transforms to the Tweenmax commands 
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fmf9vLry/10/).
I've also noticed that transformOrigin should be copied carefully, as the nested elements don't get positioned the same way as they do when their transformOrigin is set via css.

```
#coffee {transform-origin: 517px 484px;}
```

=

```
TweenMax.set("#coffee",{transformOrigin:"517px 484px"});
```

but

```
#coffee-badge {transform-origin: 445px 488px;}
```

=

```
TweenMax.set("#coffee-badge",{transformOrigin:"100% 50%"})
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use TweenMax.